# ProGuard - Obfuscate and Shrink "app" module only?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I am trying to use ProGuard first time to obfuscate only "app" module of my project. But i either face problems generating apk or the generated apk simply crash the app.

I have already tried following ProGuard rule:

> -keep class !com.example.mypackage.**{ *; }

But it generates following error:

> Warning:library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or
>   implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser

So i want to know if i can just obfuscate and shrink only single module without using any other functionality.

Comment: what all libs are you using

Comment: It will not work for you if you just obfuscate a single module (e.g. app) because all other library or android packages which is also the part of your application, will not understand your obfuscated module's classes or InnerClasses.

Comment: The other modules are just libraries I am using in app module. The other modules are not dependent on it.

Answer (score 0):

The rule itself will not create this warning. It looks like you included something as compile dependency that contains the `XmlPullParser` class which is already present in the Android SDK jar.

This warnings is usually harmless and can be ignored by adding `-ignorewarnings` to your ProGuard configuration, but I would check all your dependencies and investigate where this class is included from.